# Copying curl request from Chrome to Postman doesn't work as expected

Tags: curl, postman

I am trying to copy the curl from [this website](https://ocrportal.hhs.gov/ocr/breach/breach_report.jsf) to postman.

I want to copy the request when clicking on the following button:

[image]

I opened DevTools in the Network tab to see copy the request:

[image]

and then I import to postman:

[image]

But in Postman, I get HTML response, while chrome downloads an xls file. Why does Postman fail to download the file? Does anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From whatever reason the body is not copied to Postman request. When I copy it manually from the browser's network tab:

[image]

I can get the xml format, then I can click on Save Response => Save to a file, and it offers me to save it as "breach_report.xls".

Comment: You have no idea how much I'm grateful, I'm on this for a couple of days, it helped me to solve a bug in my app.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the carrot new line/option terminator that Chrome adds for each new option. **So if you remove the carrots (^ or /) at the end of each line it will work.** Make sure there is a space where the new line terminates. Remove the ^ or / and it should be fine. End line terminator could be different depending on the Curl option from Chrome.

For example change (does not import):

```
 curl "https://myapi.restapis.com/insurance/claims/attachment" ^
      -H "authority: myapi.restapis.com"  ^
      -H "accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"  ^
      -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9"  ^
      -H "authorization: Bearer --bearer token etc."  ^
      -H "content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"  ^
      -H "location-timezone: Eastern Standard Time"  ^
      -H "origin: ^
    https:///apis.restapis.com" ^
      -H "timezone: Eastern Standard Time"  ^
      --compressed
```

To this (***does import***):

```
curl "https://myapi.restapis.com/insurance/claims/attachment"
      -H "authority: myapi.restapis.com" 
      -H "accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" 
      -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9" 
      -H "authorization: Bearer --bearer token etc." 
      -H "content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" 
      -H "location-timezone: Eastern Standard Time" 
      -H "origin:
    https:///apis.restapis.com"
      -H "timezone: Eastern Standard Time" 
      --compressed
```

Should be good to import into Postman from Chrome curl.